# Setting up a Stack in C

Tags: c, stack

I am working on basic stack methods and I have to make it so that my stack can accept characters. I need to use the push and pop methods I have to load and unload strings(i.e. "bob", "SELUR LOBOC") from the stack then print out the results.  This is what I have so far:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
int stack[5]= {1,2,3,4,5};
int top;

void init()
{
//set stack top pointer too -1
top = -1;
}

void push(int x)
{
//increment stack pointer
top = top+1;
//place x on top of stack
stack[top] = x;
}
int pop(){
int x;
//retrieve item from top of stack.
x = stack[top];
//decrement stack
top = top-1;
return x;
}

boolean isStackEmpty(){
boolean empty;
empty = false;
//if top = -1, the stack is empty
if(top == -1){
    empty = true;
}
return empty;
}
int main(void)
{
printf(pop);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: No indentation, for one.

Comment: Missing blank lines between functions would be no. 2.

Comment: No stack underflow check on pop()

Comment: You need to write a function called `SKCUS_LOBOC`. That's the only way you can unload strings. They might seem to load right but you'll get into trouble if you try to unload them....

Comment: No stack overflow check on push().

Comment: Also, "SELUR LOBOC" will not work, try "SKCUS LOBOC"

Comment: int stack[5] why?  Why pick 5?  Stop bean-counting and just put in 4096 to start with.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit: Good point. Beans aren't permitted in `SELUR_LOBOC`... Hence the suggestion of `SKCUS_LOBOC`...

Comment: Since `printf(pop)` passes the function  pointer to `pop` as the first argument to `printf()`, but `printf()` expects a `char *`, you have major problems immediately.  You don't show any code reading characters, pushing them onto the stack, or popping them off.  You're not going to be able to fit 'COBOL RULES' onto a 5-character stack — you need to allocate more space, and you don't need to pre-initialize it since you're going to overwrite the pre-initialized values anyway.

Comment: `boolean` is undefined.

Comment: @ThingyWotsit I just put 5 in.  I wasn't sure what to put in there.  I just know I have to use the push and pop methods to load and unload the strings from the stack, then print the results.

Comment: The strings are: "bob”; “snoino dna revil etah I”;   “SELUR LOBOC”

Answer (score 0, accepted):

like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

typedef bool boolean;

typedef char* Type;

#define PRN_TYPE "%s"

enum { CAPACITY = 5, EMPTY = -1 };

Type stack[CAPACITY];

int top = EMPTY;

void init(void){
    top = EMPTY;
}

void push(Type x){
    if(top+1 < CAPACITY){
        stack[++top] = x;
    } else {
        fprintf(stderr, "Stack full! Can't push '" PRN_TYPE "'.\n", x);
    }
}

Type pop(void){
    return stack[top--];
}

boolean isStackEmpty(void){
    return top == EMPTY;
}

int main(void){
    init();
    push("red");
    push("blue");
    push("green");
    push("yellow");
    push("brown");
    push("purple");

    while(!isStackEmpty()){
        printf(PRN_TYPE "\n", pop());
    }
}
```

Comment: I need to do it with certain strings.  And the characters of the string go into the stack.  For instance: "SELUR LOBOC" the characters need to be pushed onto the stack then popped out and it should print out as "COBOL RULES"

Comment: @Mrs.Jones Yes It does. E.g Use `char` as `Type`.

Comment: Ok. Thank you. How would rewrite the code using objects?

Comment: @Mrs.Jones For non-primitive types `printf` can not be used like this, so You need to implement output functions.

Comment: I now need to rewrite this code to using a queue.  How would I do that?

Comment: @Mrs.Jones You need to manage the beginning and end of the queue. It may be easier to use lists than to use arrays. There are many examples on this site. Anyway, please post a new question.